# Single app on same machine acting as a socketio Server and client at the same time

Tags: python, socket.io, client-server

I am working on a project and it requires from a single machine running an app to be acting as a socketio server and client at the same time. Seperate libraries for client and server will be imported to the app code. The app will be written in python for linux.

Libraries I will be using for the python client and server are as follows:

[Socketio Server Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-socketio/1.5.1)

[Socketio Client Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client)

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are having?

Comment: Questions posted to SO are usually phrased as...well...questions.  They generally include code attempts you've made and a detailed description of what isn't working.

Comment: well, I guess this won't work in python with current libraries because the client library and the server library both have a blocking loop to wait or listen for incoming communication messages. I have got it resolved in javascript of nodejs and socketio. May be playing with eventlet etc would resolve, but I don't have any idea right now. Any suggesstions please?